# Bazaar launchpad-login issue

Tags: bazaar, launchpad

I have registered on launchpad website but every time I attempt to execute

```
bzr launchpad-login username@email.com
```

It gives me this error

> bzr: ERROR: The user name username@email.com is not registered on
>   Launchpad.

Did anyone do something else other than registering on the launchpad?

Comment: So, does the answer solve your issue ? If so, please accept it or give details about your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with your **launchpad user-id** instead of email:

Have a look to the documentation of this function:
http://doc.bazaar.canonical.com/plugins/en/launchpad-plugin.html

Comment: Exactly. The launchpad-login command works with user id, NOT with email. See also `bzr launchpad-login --help`. Btw a shortcut of the command is `bzr lp-login`.